# Help in constructing/ verifying proof about convergence of subsequences

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

> Let $(x_n)$ be a real sequence. Let $L$ be the set of those $x ∈
> \mathbb R$ for which there is a subsequence of $(x_n)$ that converges
>   to $x$. Which of the following subsets of $\mathbb R$ can occur as $L$? $∅,
>  \{0\},\{0,1\}, \mathbb Z, \mathbb Q, \mathbb R.$

I'm fine with the first three but the last few are giving me issues.

I'm leaning towards thinking that $\mathbb Z$ can occur as $L$. I'm having great difficulty in showing this though. (My intuition initially made me think otherwise). First let a subsequence of $(x_n)$ that converges to, say, $i$, be $(x_{i_j})$ (so that $x_{i_1}$ is the first term in the subsequence, $x_{i_2}$ the second, etc) so that $x_{i_j} \ne x_{a_b}$ unless $i=a, j=b$. I was thinking along the lines of since you can form a bijection between $\mathbb Z $and $\mathbb Z \mathsf x\mathbb Z$, we could form a map between the set of integers to the set $(i,j)$ across all $i,j$. Does this show that you can infinitely many infinite subsequences? If so then just set $(x_{i_j})$ to converge to $i$ and we have shown that $\mathbb Z$ can occur as $L$.

If not why not/ alternate way of going about it? I am assuming since you can't form such bijections between $\mathbb Z$ and $\mathbb R$ or $\mathbb Q$ that they cannot occur as $L$. I would also like to know if this suffices to show that please.

Apolgies if that was very messy and hard to follow, I've never tackled a question like this before and as you can probably tell I am struggling to organise my thoughts. I am really in need of help in better constructing this proof (if it is one).

Thank you

Comment: For $\Bbb R$: $\Bbb Q$ is countable, so we can enumerate it as $\{q_n:n\in\Bbb N\}$. Show that if $x$ is any real number, the sequence $\langle q_n:n\in\Bbb N\rangle$ has a subsequence converging to $x$.

Answer (score 0):

For $\mathbb{Z}$, consider

$$0,1,0,1,-1,0,1,-1,2,0,1,-1,2,-2,\dots$$

Can you see the pattern? Every integer appears an infinite number of times.

To see that $\mathbb{Q}$ can't be such a set, take a sequence $\{q_k\}$ of rational numbers that converges to an irrational number $\alpha$. For each $k$, there is a subsequence of $\{x_n\}$ which converges to $q_n$. Use this to construct a subsequence of $\{x_n\}$ that converges to $\alpha$. Conclude that $\alpha\in L=\mathbb{Q}$, which is a contradiction.